# Is there any lightbox-script which doesn't need a html-anchor

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, lightbox, javascript

I'm looking for a library or script to open a single image in a lightbox.
All the libs I found so far do need a html-anchor as parent-tag of the image and a thumbnail.

```
<a href="image.jpg" class="popout"><img src="thmumbnail.jpg"></a>
```

I don't have any thumbnails since I'm loading/embedding the pics directly from an online storage place in "web-friendly" resolution/size. So what I would like to be able to do, is something like this:

```
<img class="popout" src="www.photobucket.com/myimage.jpg" height="300" width="500">
```

while the height/width would be specified in a css as well. One reasen I would like to do it that way is, I already have articles written with about 100pics. So I don't want to embed them all in anchors...

so back to the question: is there a lib or script that let me do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Colorbox: http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox

Then your code can look like this:

```
$(".popout").on("click", showImage);
function showImage(e)
{
    $.colorbox({href:$(e.currentTarget).attr("src")});
}
```

Comment: hi thanks for your answer. The script would then go into the <head> section, right ? And shouldn't .attr("href") be changed to .attr("src") since the img.src contains the information ?

Answer (score 4):

Get a fresh `lightbox.js` file from here: [Lightbox 2 plugin](http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/)
Open `lightbox.js` in any editor:
Find the below written code:

```
Lightbox.prototype.enable = function() {
  var _this = this;
  return $('body').on('click', 'a[rel^=lightbox], area[rel^=lightbox]', function(e) {
    _this.start($(e.currentTarget));
    return false;
  });
};
```

In that replace third line with following code:

```
return $('body').on('click', 'img[rel^=lightbox], area[rel^=lightbox]', function(e) {
```

Now inside `lightbox.js` search for the word `href` and replace it with `src`. Do this for all `href` in that `.js` file.
Include this `.js` file in your project.
HTML code for your image will become:

```
<img class="popout" 
     src="www.photobucket.com/myimage.jpg" 
     rel="lightbox[plants]" 
     title="Say something about this image">
```

Basically what we are changing is

- adding `rel` attribute:
    If two or more images contains same `rel` attribute they will shown as image set.
- Adding Title attribue:
  It will just show info of your image on light box.

**UPDATE:**
If your thumbnail image src is different than your actual image src then you can add one more attribute to the `<image>` as `value`:

```
<img class="popout" 
     src="thumbnail path" 
     value="actual image path"
     rel="lightbox[plants]" 
     title="Say something about this image">
```

But again to add this you have to change the `href` keyword from `lightbox.js` to `value`.
Then you all done.

Comment: in recent version only one or two hrefs should be replaced, the others are not needed.

Answer (score 2):

You can use pretty much **any lightbox-like script** which has ability to call it **manually**. Example (using [fancybox](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/)): http://jsfiddle.net/eXaGn/

Like with fancbybox:

```
$("img").click(function() {    
    $.fancybox.open(this.src);    
    return false;    
});​
```

Answer (score 0):

I needed a similar functionality and decided on SimpalModal

http://www.ericmmartin.com/projects/simplemodal/

I liked that you could pass in a html string and it would generate the modal from that and I could generate a modal programatically, no need for embedded content nor  tags to trigger the modal